# Using LINQ How to access values of List item inside a Class

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two classes `MoviesListRootObject` and `Response`. `MoviesListRootObject` conatins list of `Response` I want to access the id, Title and description that comes to `List<Response>` and assign that to var.

```
public class MoviesListRootObject
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
    public List<Response> response { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class Response
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string title_language { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string description_language { get; set; }
}
```

Now What I can think of writing LINQ  to get MovieDetails object containing reponse but that wont help.

```
var movieResponse = from MoviesListRootObject movieDetail in rootObj
    select new MovieDetails
    {
         Response =movieDetail.response
    };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve. My answer assumes that you simply want to have the properties of all Responses in all MoviesListRootObject:

```
var result = rootObj.SelectMany(x => x.response)
                    .Select(x => new { x.id, x.title, x.description });
```

You don't even need an anonymous class here:

```
var result = rootObj.SelectMany(x => x.response);
// result will be of type IEnumerable<Response>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var movieResponse = rootObj
                    .SelectMany(m => m.response)
                    .Select(m => new {
                       id = m.id, // or just m.id, as name is the same
                       title = m.title, //idem
                       description = m.description //idem
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)?

```
var allResponses = rootObj.SelectMany(d => d.Response);
```

Will give you all the `Response`s for all movies in `rootObj`.

---

if `rootObj` is in fact an instance of `MoviesListRootObject` you don't need `SelectMany`,

```
var responses = rootObj.response;
```

will do.